# How to redirect IP to domain?

Tags: apache, htaccess, redirects, duplicate-content, httpd.conf

My IP *xxx.xxx.xxx.xx* is pointing to `example.com` at GoDaddy but I just noticed that when I type the IP in browser, it doesn't redirect to the website, how can do this? I am sure this will happen through *httpd.conf* but unsure about what I need to add.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the .htaccess file to redirect from IP to domain using this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^555\.555\.555\.555
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Change `555.555.555.555` to match the IP of your server, additionally though you can use canonical urls that will prevent duplicates entering Googles index, Check out: [Should I redirect the site IP address to the domain name](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/44844/20604).

Comment: Hi @bybe, actually I am using ruby on rails so there is no .htaccess file and I only make changes in .httpd.conf file, can you tell me that code for that ?

Comment: You should be able to create a .htaccess file yourself, I'm not to familiar with Ruby on Rails but I'm assuming this is just running on Apache.